# Set General Link Internal Path Globally

Tags: sitecore-client, link-manager, renderfield

Has anyone set the start path of the General Link field globally when choosing internal? I can do it per item/template, but looks like it requires custom code to have it applied globally. I thought there would be a OOB setting, but I believe there is not. I looked at gneralink.xml and internallink.xml, but was not able to override that functionality. Not sure if that is the correct code to override though.

Comment: Hi. Have you consider creating a base template for a General Link field, where you set the Source and inherit from it on all content templates that require a Link field? This way no customization is required.

Comment: I ended up just changing it for each template that needed it. If creating new templates though probably would of gone with a base template.